# Gnuplot: 4d color plot using matrix format

Tags: graph, charts, gnuplot

I know that for a 4d color plot (3d surface, and the color is given by a 4th field), I can use a datafile of the format

```
# X Y Z C
  1 1 0 4
  1 2 1 3

  2 1 4 2
  2 2 4 5
  ...
```

and then use

```
set pm3d
splot "datafile.dat" u 1:2:3:4 with pm3d
```

On the other hand, I know how to make a simple surface plot where the X and Y values are implicit while the Z value is in matrix format:

```
#Z DATA ONLY
0 1
4 4

splot "datafile.dat" matrix
```

Is there a way to make 4d color plots using this matrix format? For example, taking the Z data from one file and the corresponding color data from another file, or combining both the Z value and the color into a single file in matrix format?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, this does appear possible. See the examples below.

1. http://www.gnuplotting.org/tag/matrix/

   > All we need to create such a plot is the `image` plot style, and of
   >   course the data have to be in a proper format. Suppose the following
   >   matrix which represents z-values of a measurement.
   >
   > ```
   > 0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0
   > 0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0
   > 0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0
   > 0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0
   > 0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0
   > 0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0
   > 0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0
   > 0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0
   > 0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0
   > ```
   >
   > In order to plot these values in different gray color tones, we
   >   specify the corresponding `palette`. In addition we apply the above
   >   mentioned `image` plot style and the `matrix` format option. The result is
   >   shown in Fig. 2.
   >
   > ```
   > set palette grey
   > plot 'color_map.dat' matrix with image
   > ```
   >
   > [image: z values with color]
2. http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/heatmaps.html

   > ```
   > #
   > # Two ways of generating a 2D heat map from ascii data
   > #
   >
   > set title "Heat Map generated from a file containing Z values only"
   > unset key
   > set tic scale 0
   >
   > # Color runs from white to green
   > set palette rgbformula -7,2,-7
   > set cbrange [0:5]
   > set cblabel "Score"
   > unset cbtics
   >
   > set xrange [-0.5:4.5]
   > set yrange [-0.5:4.5]
   >
   > set view map
   > splot '-' matrix with image
   > 5 4 3 1 0
   > 2 2 0 0 1
   > 0 0 0 1 0
   > 0 0 0 2 3
   > 0 1 2 4 3
   > e
   > e
   > ```
   >
   > [image: Heat map generated from a file only containing z values]

Comment: These are 3D plots, not 4D plots as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is what the original question was after.

My understanding was that he wants to draw colored spheres in 3d space, such that XYZ are the coordinates and C is the color intensity. Is this the case ?

Comment: This does not answer the question. If you wish to comment on another answer, use the commenting feature.